# What is the best way to check if a User has access to an Entity

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I got simplified the following relationship in my database.

```
1 User -> n Projects
1 Project -> n Tasks
etc.
```

So now I catch myself often in the Code doing the following

```
// Get the current logged in User
$user = Session::getUser();
$project = $this->projects->findById($project_id);
if ( ! $project->hasOwner($user))
   // user does not own the project
```

And thats gets worse with the relationship the project has. For example then I have to check if the User owns the projects and then if the tasks belongs to the project.

I was thinking maybe use Eager Loading here, so I can just filter on the given results. But then the database has to load more data then often is required. right ?

```
// Get the current logged in User
$user = Session::getUser();
$project = $user->projects()->find($project_id);
if ( ! $project)
   // user does not own the project
```

**But even if I do it that way it feels repetitive and hacky. I was wondering if there is maybe a better way to approach that ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst users have access to their project, you need to make provision for sharing projects with other users in the future and their access types.

Hence, a `project_permission` table is highly recommended.

Structure should be as follows:

id | project_id | grantee_user_id | access_user_id | type | created_at | updated_at | deleted_at

You'll have 3 types of permission:

1. Owner - Full permission
2. Edit Access
3. Read only access

Your Permission Model:

```
class ProjectPermission extends Eloquent {
     protected $table = "project_permission";

     /*
     *  Types
     */

     const OWNER = 1;
     const EDIT = 2;
     const READ = 3;

     /*
     *  Scopes
     */

    public function scopeOwner($query)
    {
        return $query->whereType(self::OWNER);
    }

    public function scopeEdit($query)
    {
        return $query->whereType(self::EDIT);
    }

    public function scopeRead($query)
    {
        return $query->whereType(self::READ);
    }

    public function project()
    {
        return $this->belongTo('Project','project_id');
    }

}
```

And Project model:

```
class Project extends Eloquent {
    ...
    //Always eager load project permission
    public $with = ['permission'];

    public function permission()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('ProjectPermission','project_id');
    }

    public function scopeUserIsOwner($query,$user_id)
    {
        return $query->has('permission'=>function($q){
            return $q->owner()->where('access_user_id','=',$user_id);
        });
    }

    public function scopeCurrentUserIsOwner($query,$user_id)
    {
        $user = Session::getUser();
        $user_id = $user ? $user->id : 0;

        return $query->has('permission'=>function($q){
            return $q->owner()->where('access_user_id','=',$user_id);
        });
    }

    /*
    *  @param int $user_id
    *  @return boolean
    */
    public function hasAccessOwner($user_id)
    {
        return (bool)$this->permission()->whereType(\ProjectPermission::OWNER)->->whereAccessUserId($user_id)->count();
    }
}
```

Ideally, you should be loading only projects where the user has access. And if the need arises to check for access, the `hasAccess..` functions will prove handy.